# Comma delimited list of row values

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, db2

I currently have a database structured similar to this:

```
Name | v_BirthDate | v_Drivers_License | v_SSN 
-----------------------------------------------
Anna |      1      |         0         |   1
Bob  |      0      |         1         |   0
Cal  |      1      |         1         |   1 
Dave |      0      |         0         |   1
```

The basic idea of the database is to see how the person was verified in a system; whether the person was verified in the system using their birth date, driver's license number, or their social.

What I would like to do is to take the row for each person and create another column that shows a list of the used verification methods in a comma-separated format.

Something similar to this:

```
Name | v_BirthDate | v_Drivers_License | v_SSN |    list 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Anna |      1      |         0         |   1   | BirthDate,SSN
Bob  |      0      |         1         |   0   | Drivers_License
Cal  |      1      |         1         |   1   | BirthDate,Drivers_License,SSN
Dave |      0      |         0         |   1   | SSN
```

I used the WITH clause to create a temporary table that changes the 1s to the string variable such as BirthDate, Drivers_License, and SSN. However, I am not sure how I am able to create the list column. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a giant `case` and some string logic:

```
select t.*,
       trim(leading ',' from
            (case when v_BirthDate = 1 then ',BirthDate' else '' end) ||
            (case when v_Drivers_License = 1 then ',Drivers_License' else '' end) ||
            (case when v_SSN = 1 then ',v_SSN' else '' end)
           ) as list
from t;
```

This creates a string composed of each component preceded by a comma.  The `trim()` removes the initial comma.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I tried both queries and they were both perfect. However, your query seemed more logical for what I was looking for. One thing, would you mind explaining what the trim-leading clause does in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
with x as (
  select
      name, v_birthdate, v_drivers_license, v_ssn,
      case when v_birthdate = 1 then ',BirthDate' else '' end ||
      case when v_drivers_license = 1 then ',Drivers_License' else '' end ||
      case when v_ssn = 1 then ',SSN' else '' end as list
    from my_table
)
select 
    name, v_birthdate, v_drivers_license, v_ssn,
    case when list = '' then list else substr(list, 2) end as list
  from x;
```